# Getting last 7 days data on perticular entity and displaying in SSRS report

Tags: charts, reporting-services

I have case entity in that I need to get how many cases created in last 7 days and closed in last 7 days. this I need to show it on chart every day for last 7days how many closed and created.

Can some one help on this. I have written SQL query to fetch but it is not working or should I have to go for expression?

Comment: Can you paste the SQL with your question and show example data?

Comment: Select DATENAME(DW,DayN)S,opened, closed from(select orderdate as DayN,count(1) as opened,0 closed from tablecase where orderdate is not nullgroup by orderdate union all select duedate as dayn,0opened,count(1) as closed from tablecase where duedate is not null group by duedate) as p order by dayN asc

Comment: it has to show created on and resolved on as 2 columns in chart and show these everyday for about last 7 days

Answer (score 0):

This will produce the last 7 days even if there is no data by using a calendar table.

```
WITH 
calendar
AS 
(
   SELECT 
        [date] = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
      , [day_count] = 1
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 
        [date] = DATEADD(DAY, -1, [date])
      , [day_count] = [day_count] + 1
   FROM 
      [calendar]
   WHERE
      [day_count] < 7
)
,
tablecase
AS
(
   SELECT tbl.* FROM (VALUES
    ( 1, '01-Jan-2023', '11-Jan-2023')
   , ( 2, '01-Jan-2023', '12-Jan-2023')
   , ( 3, '03-Jan-2023', '13-Jan-2023')
   , ( 4, '04-Jan-2023', '14-Jan-2023')
   , ( 5, '06-Jan-2023', '15-Jan-2023')
   , ( 6, '06-Jan-2023', '16-Jan-2023')
   , ( 7, '06-Jan-2023', '17-Jan-2023')
   , ( 8, '11-Jan-2023', '18-Jan-2023')
   , ( 9, '11-Jan-2023', '19-Jan-2023')
   , ( 10, '11-Jan-2023', '20-Jan-2023')
   , ( 11, '11-Jan-2023', '21-Jan-2023')
   , ( 12, '12-Jan-2023', '22-Jan-2023')
   , ( 13, '13-Jan-2023', '23-Jan-2023')
   , ( 14, '14-Jan-2023', '24-Jan-2023')
   , ( 15, '15-Jan-2023', '25-Jan-2023')
   , ( 16, '16-Jan-2023', '26-Jan-2023')
   ) tbl ([item_id], [orderdate], [duedate]) 
)
SELECT 
    cal.[date]
   , [closed] = ISNULL([closed], 0)
   , [opened] = ISNULL([opened], 0)
FROM
   calendar AS cal
   LEFT JOIN 
   (
      SELECT 
            [date] = CAST([orderdate] AS DATE)
          , [measure] = COUNT(1)  
          , [action] = 'closed'
      FROM 
         [tablecase]
      WHERE 
         [orderdate] IS NOT NULL
      GROUP BY 
         [orderdate]
      UNION ALL
      SELECT 
            [date] = CAST([duedate] AS DATE)
          , [measure] = COUNT(1) 
          , [action] = 'opened'
      FROM 
         [tablecase]
      WHERE 
         [duedate] IS NOT NULL
      GROUP BY 
         [duedate]
) AS a
PIVOT
   (
      SUM([measure]) FOR [action] IN 
      (
         [closed], [opened]
      )
) AS pvt ON pvt.[date] = cal.[date];
```

[image]